# Does anyone know of a LESS CSS "theme sheet"?

Tags: css, less

I am wondering if anyone knows of something like JQuery's Themeroller, but would generate a lot of the color values based off of setting a few LESS color variables?

Ideally, you would set a few base values (header font color and header background color, maybe) and things like borders, ASIDE font color, etc. would be calculated using fairly prosaic design color rules for the standard page elements.

Just not wanting to re-invent the wheel, here, especially given my lousy designs.  :)

p.s.  Thanks, bchhun.  I had looked at Bootstrap at the start, but I am going with the Semantic Grid.  To be honest, I am loving Semantic Grid and LESS from a programming standpoint, but I am just pathetic at design.  hence, I wanted something that used LESS and a bunch-of-math-operations-within-a-stylesheet to make a halfway decent-looking draft app at project outset.  Then a real designer or the customer could tweak the color values.

Comment: yea http://semantic.gs/ might just be the best LessCSS based grid system out there. I'll try it in my future projects as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Or you may build your own.

Comment: I've used this in the past, great starting point for a website.